# Best way to go through list of computer names and perform actions on each name in the list? -Python

Tags: python

I have a program that takes a list of computer names from serverlist.txt.
I want it to perform a function on each computer name.

What would be the best way to pull from a list?  (The code I need to edit is at the bottom  of the source)

I am having a problem in which it is only reading the last computer name in the list properly.  I get an error name saying computer name doesn't exist on all other computer names.  Even though the names are correct.  I can change the order of them and the last name on the list always goes through properly.

**UPDATE**
Here is what I am trying now:

```
import os
import shutil
import fileinput
import pypyodbc
import re  # used to replace string
import sys # prevents extra lines being inputed in config
           # example: sys.stdout.write

def copyfiles():
    # copy config to remote server
    source = os.listdir("C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/PythonUpdate/") # directory where original configs are located
    destination = '//' + servername + '/c$/test/' # destination server directory
    for files in source:
        if files.endswith(".config"):
            shutil.copy(files,destination)

def locationid(results, connection):
    # replace original location id with the correct one obtained above in SQL query
    source = "C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/PythonUpdate/Super.config"
    newtext = str(results[1])
    with fileinput.FileInput(source, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            pattern = r'(?<=locationId=")\d+'  # find 1 or more digits that come
                                              # after the string locationid            
            if re.search(pattern, line):
                sys.stdout.write(re.sub(pattern, newtext, line)) # adds number after locationid
                fileinput.close()
            else:
                sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r'(locationId=)"', r'\1"' + newtext, line)) # use sys.stdout.write instead of "print"
                # using re module to format                                                              
                # adds a location id number after locationid even if there was no number originally there        
                fileinput.close()
    connection.close()
    copyfiles()

def replaceid(servername):    
    cursor = connection.cursor() 
    SQLCommand = ("SELECT Name, Location_ID "      
        "FROM dbo.table_name "   # table name
        "with (nolock)"
        "WHERE Name = ?")
    Values = [servername]
    cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    if results:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print (" ")
        print (" Name: " + results[0] + " Location ID: " + str(results[1]))
        print (" ")
        print (" Config file copied to " + servername + ".")
        print (" ")
        locationid(results, connection) # calls locationid() and carrys over results and connection
    else:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print (" ")
        print (" Does not exist.")
        print (" ")
        connection.close()

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
array = []
with open("C:/Users/myusers/Desktop/PythonUpdate/serverlist.txt", "r") as f:
    for servername in f:
        try:
            connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=;Database=;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
            sqlstate = ex.args[0]
            if sqlstate == '28000':
                print ("You do not have access.")
        replaceid(servername)
```

An explanation of what it's doing...

It gets the servername, goes through replaceid() which grabs an ID from a SQL Database.
Calls locationid() which replaces the ID in a config file with the ID from SQL.
Calls copyfiles() which copys the updated config file to the servername on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the server name as a parameter:

```
with open("C:/mypath/serverlist.txt", "r") as f:
    for servername in f:
        replaceid(servername)
```

Now change your `replaceid()` function to accept a parameter and you should be good.

General rule: Avoid functions that depend on global variables. Write functions that expect parameters instead.

Comment: Another general rule: Move `pypyodbc.connect` out of the eventual loop

Comment: Absolutely, that as well.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm still getting an issue where it's not reading previous computer names properly.  it goes through the list and says all the names are invalid except for the last on the list.

Comment: Well, I can't help you with that. Are you sure the names are valid? Maybe you need to `strip()` them before passing them to the DB? That's really something you need to figure out yourself. You have the input data, you have the database, I haven't.

Comment: I'll read up on strip.  The names are correct.  I can take one of the first names on the list and move it to the last of the list.  Only the last of the list reads properly.

Comment: Write the function so that it accepts parameters. Call it manually a few times with different server names for testing. See that it works. Then make it work in a loop. Debugging 101. Be methodical.