# How to remove \n in this line?

Tags: python

I have a part of my program that reads lines from a `.txt` file.  Each line is a computername.  It takes the computername as a variable and inputs it into a directory name.  I am getting an error that says

No such file or directory: `//COMPUTERNAME\n/c$/test`

How do I remove the `\n` so that it will create a directory name of `//COMPUTERNAME/c$/test`.

Here is the part of my code I am having issues with:

```
import os
import shutil
import fileinput
import re  # used to replace string
import sys # prevents extra lines being inputed in config
           # example: sys.stdout.write

def copyfiles(servername):
    # copy config to remote server
    source = os.listdir("C:/Users/name/Desktop/PythonUpdate") # directory where original configs are located
    destination = '//' + servername + '/c$/test/' # destination server directory
    for files in source:
        if files.endswith(".config"):
            shutil.copy(files,destination)

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
f = open("C:/Users/jm09580/Desktop/PythonUpdateOasis/serverlist.txt", "r")
for servername in f:
    copyfiles(servername)
```

**UPDATE** 
This works:

```
array = []
with open("C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/PythonUpdate/serverlist.txt", "r") as f:
for servername in f:
    copyfiles(servername.strip())
```

Comment: You don't need `re`. Just use the regular `str.replace()` function: `servername = servername.replace('\n')` or `copyfiles(servername.replace('\n'))`.

Comment: Hm, I thought you would [read up on `strip()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267173/best-way-to-go-through-list-of-computer-names-and-perform-actions-on-each-name-i/44267285?noredirect=1#comment75543771_44267285)?

Comment: I did but I'm not having any luck with strip().  Christian, ignore the re.  I'm using that for another function in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove whitespace characters, which includes the newline character `\n` you can use `strip()`, so your last two lines become:

```
for servername in f:
    copyfiles(servername.strip())
```

Comment: Good point. I didn't think about the OP having to remove other whitespace characters. using `strip()` is a better idea.

Comment: I get an error that says servername is not defined.

Comment: It is being defined in the `for` statement, maybe a copy-paste error?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
copyfiles(servername.strip())
```

Which should get rid of spaces and new lines